# ER diagrams: One (optional) to one (mandatory)?

Tags: entity-relationship, draw.io

I'm new to ER diagrams. I noticed that [draw.io](https://www.draw.io) (which was recommended on Stackoverflow) does not have a one (optional) to one (mandatory) relationship.

Let's say, I have two tables "user" (id, affiliate_id) and "affiliate" (id). There doesn't have to be an affiliate, in which case user.affiliate_id would be null.

However, if there is an affiliate, then user.affiliate_id will link to affiliate.id.

So wouldn't that be a one (optional) to one (mandatory) relationship?

PS: I was thinking that maybe user.affiliate_id must not be null in a strict sense. However, it doesn't break the foreign key constraints (at least for SQLite 3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are describing a one-to-many relationship.  One user can (optionally) be associated to one affiliate, but the same affiliate can be associated to more than one user.

Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You're right. Looks like I was totally off the track. Thank you! (I have to wait for a couple of minutes before I can accept your answer.)

Comment: But this doesn't cover the case in the OP, where a user can optionally have one affiliate, but an affiliate must have exactly one user. There is now a one mandatory to one optional. :-)

Comment: Sorry for excavating a dead thread, but how can there be a one to one relationship with both mandatory and optional users? Surely this means that if the optional user isn’t there it will be forced to be null instead of not there since the user is mandatory? Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, that would be a zero/one (or zero/many) to one relationship type, which has to be shown in the diagram. There are different notations for ER diagrams (and it's therefore, in fact, preferable to use UML class diagrams). For instance, in the [notation used by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a81358/05_deva.gif) the optional end of the connection line representing the relationship type is annotated with both a zero and a one symbol. In UML, the annotation of the optional association end would be `0..1` (if single-valued) or `0..*` (if many-valued).

Comment: As Mark pointed out, I was wrong in that I was assuming a one to one relationship instead of a one to many relationship. Thanks for the information on the different notations. That's a good point!